# Is it possible to infer parent component props based on child component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I want to make a `Tabs` component that infers the possible values of the `active` prop based on what its children have as `name` props. This is how I tried to do it:

```
import React from 'react'

interface TabProps<N extends string> {
  name: N
}

function Tab<N extends string>(props: TabProps<N>) {
  return null
}

type TabsType<N extends string = string> =
  | React.FunctionComponentElement<TabProps<N>>
  | React.FunctionComponentElement<TabProps<N>>[]

interface TabsProps<Tabs extends TabsType> {
  children: Tabs
  active: Tabs extends TabsType<infer N> ? N : unknown
}

export function Tabs<Tabs extends TabsType>(props: TabsProps<Tabs>) {
  return null
}

const test = (
  {/* I want active to be inferred as type 'bla' | 'hey' */}
  <Tabs active="blabla"> 
    <Tab name="bla" />
    <Tab name="hey" />
  </Tabs>
)
```

The problem here seems to be that the `Tabs` type parameter of the `Tabs` component gets inferred as `JSX.Element` instead of `React.FunctionComponentElement<TabProps<N>>[]` which has the consequence that the default type `string` gets used instead, making the invalid value `blabla` go unnoticed by typescript.

Does this have a workaround? Is this a fundamental limitation of JSX? Is this something that needs a feature request? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it seems not to be possible to infer parent props based on the types of its children at this moment. JSX expressions will always end up being of type `JSX.Element`. It is a limitation of the way JSX type checking is implemented currently. However, [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14729) addresses this problem, so there is hope that this will become possible in later versions of typescript.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it can work the way you are imagining it, because TypeScript cannot infer that kind of type information just from the JSX children of a component. I'd be very curious if someone else has a solution that would make that work in any semblance you're trying for.

Your best bet is probably to abstract the children of `<Tabs>` into an object, which you *can* infer strict (literal) type information for. Then, using generics, you can extract the explicit (literal) `name` values and enforce it on the `active` prop. `<Tabs>` will simply map its `data` array into rendered JSX, a very common pattern in React.

```
import React from 'react'

function Tabs<D extends readonly {name: string}[]>({data, active}: {data: D, active: D[number]["name"]}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(ea => {
        return <div className={active === ea.name ? 'active' : ''}>{ea.name}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const tabData = [
  {
    name: 'bla'
  },
  {
    name: 'hey'
  }
] as const;

const test = (
  <Tabs data={tabData} active="bla" />
)
```

Try it on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTMBXAOw2AmrgBUUAjAZwB4AROJADxhJqAE3ZwiKEQwA2ATzgBvaihBIAXHHYwowagHMAvgG0AugD4AFIpEoYKADRx0MYADckhzTbspN3Jxd3DThuY2pKEFYkKFNjACIVNXjTQwBKJVI4CSQYSihGSyzsuE4Rd3NikqVbewA6EBQwS1Q4AF5zTOrqojyC0vK3ODQZFHZ2ADlVJDbFII92tra+FDqkpDgAfgJ5pHw4TXx8Q3NFVDXpw04AekHzAG4qkvTDJ5u74rTH19I0Bm04PZWNxfO04MZioonutDqxRmRsoYHJDodNDgALJByBFwV6mZziP7UbSPX7-eBCAHLIrZTgsDhwWooWZAkH2QzOOgeNrxOEoeJwa6VNJAA). Observe that if you try and change the `active` prop to something other than "bla" or "hey" it will warn you.

Note the use of `as const` when declaring `tabData`. That has the benefit of allowing TypeScript to infer the explicit (literal) string value of the `name` properties, even though they are nested inside of an array of objects. The downside is that you can't *a priori* declare the type of `tabData` to be, e.g., an array of `TabObject`s, because by definition the shape of `tabData` must be inferred at the time of its literal declaration with `as const` in order to get that juicy strict string value inference.

However, you *do* get a useful sort of "delayed" type checking because of the way `Tabs` is defined: if the shape of `data` is invalid, `<Tabs>` will complain that it's not getting the expected shape for that prop.

Depending on your preferred React paradigm, you may dislike passing a `data` prop to `<Tabs>` and having it render its children based on that, instead of the composed approach you tried above. But by the nature of trying to infer types the way you are, I don't think it can be helped.